# Optimizing Audio Video merge

Tags: python, audio, video, moviepy

I have created simple python script to combine audio and video files of same duration. I first extract audio from a low quality video and then combine it with a HD quality video which doesn't have audio. I am encountering high overhead while trying to merge both formats it takes around 5 hours for a 3 GB video. What is the problem in this approach? Is there any ways to improve?

```
import moviepy.editor as mp

def extractaudio(videofile):
    my_clip = mp.VideoFileClip(videofile)
    my_clip.audio.write_audiofile(r"my_result.mp3")


def combine_audio(vidname, audname, outname, fps=25):
    my_clip = mp.VideoFileClip(vidname)
    audio_background = mp.AudioFileClip(audname)
    final_clip = my_clip.set_audio(audio_background)
    final_clip.write_videofile(outname,fps=fps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractaudio("../audio.3gpp")
    combine_audio("../video.mp4", "./my_result.mp3", "movie.mp4")
```

Comment: Try using FFmpeg (command line tool) as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/277642/how-to-merge-audio-and-video-file-in-ffmpeg). Try to **avoid re-encoding**. The merging takes a long time, probably because MoviePy re-encode the video (re-encoding the audio is much faster).

Comment: I am planning to use it as one of  the feature in my application.  It will be great if its achieved through a python script. As a function like mine.

Comment: You can call `ffmpeg` from a script.